# MySQL replace QUOTE

Tags: mysql

I need to replace `&quote;` in a string. I tried to do this:

```
SET `title` = REPLACE( `title`, '&quot;', '' )
```

but it gives me a parsing error.

This is the error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''&quot)' at line 1

Server version: 5.5.57-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

[image: #1064]

How do I do this?

Comment: This should work. Show the entire `UPDATE` query.

Comment: and to add to @Barmar 's comment also post the parsing error.. I have a feeling you are working on SQL Server (MSSQL) instead of MySQL..

Comment: Here is a screenshot:
[link](https://www.one-off.xyz/quot-error.jpg)

Comment: @AngryBeaver the link is not working. Could you edit your post and add the error as text instead?

Comment: I've updated the post

Comment: I've added an image with the error as well

Comment: That error does not look like it is for that query, you do not have the string `quot)` anywhere. _Additionally, your WHERE condition is probably not going to be all that helpful._

Comment: @AngryBeaver Please edit your question to include the query you have entered into the query window of phpmyadmin (do not copy the query from the result page). Also try running the SQL query from an actual php script, not via phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Progman Yes, I've already fixed my titles just using php script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple approach but it replaces all the " in string.

```
 UPDATE dummy_tab SET metatitle =REPLACE(metatitle,'/"','') WHERE metatitle LIKE '%"'
```

[image: Table Before Update]

[image: Table After Update]

Answer (score 1):

Your query should work, but it seems like the error is from another query. Anyhow:

**Try this:**

```
UPDATE tbl_name 
SET 
    field_name = REPLACE(field_name,
        string_to_find,
        string_to_replace)
WHERE
    conditions;
```

**Example:**

```
UPDATE bbb_sefurls 
SET 
    metatitle = REPLACE(metatitle,
        '&quote;',
        '');
```

*No need for a condition*

Answer (score 0):

If I'm to read your error 100% as written... you have the word quote spelled wrong some where.

```
 ...for the right syntax to use near ''&quot)'
```

notice in your error it shows no "e"   There for your replace statement would also NOT catch this.

Or more closely looking at the image you posted... you are replacing

> &quote(semicolon)

with

> ''

But the error says it is finding the string

> &quote)

somewhere in your query... Which would seem to be invalid.

Search your code for

> &quot)

Comment: The error is not saying &quote) it's saying &quot) as I have &quot)

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon `;` in `&quot;` word is the reason. Change your syntax

from

```
SET `title` = REPLACE( `title`, '&quot;', '' );
```

to

```
SET `title` = REPLACE( `title`, '&quot;', '' )#
```

and before you click Run change separator from `;` to `#`

[Look sample here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZpyM.jpg)